# Beautifulsoup replace set of html code with different code

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a set of html code in my beautifulsoup object which is to be replaced with some other code

This is what I am getting in my Beautifulsoup object

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="bt" width="100%">
<tr class="heading">
<th scope="col">Â </th>
<th class="th-heading" scope="col">B</th>
<th class="tho" scope="col"><b>O</b></th></tr></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html></html>
<th class="thm" scope="col"><b>M</b></th>
<th class="thr" scope="col"><b>R</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>W</b></th>
<th class="thecon" scope="col"><b>E</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>0s</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>F</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>S</b></th>
<th scope="col">Â </th>.............</body></html>
```

Required code:

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="bt" width="100%">
<tr class="heading">
<th scope="col">Â </th>
<th class="th-heading" scope="col">B</th>
<th class="tho" scope="col"><b>O</b></th>
<th class="thm" scope="col"><b>M</b></th>
<th class="thr" scope="col"><b>R</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>W</b></th>
<th class="thecon" scope="col"><b>E</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>0s</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>F</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>S</b></th>
<th scope="col">Â </th>.............</body></html>
```

I have tried but that's not working

```
soup.replace('<th class="tho" scope="col"><b>O</b></th></tr></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html></html>', '<th class="tho" scope="col"><b>O</b></th>')
```

Comment: That's extremely poor HTML you're starting from. BeautifulSoup will crop it to the first HTML it finds. However, your desired output isn't ideal either: you're missing closing tags for `tr` and `table`. Or can we assume this is included in the dots?

Comment: Yes.. Its included in the dots. The only thing is that its adding unwanted closing divs and html tags on the 7th line of the code. I just need to remove it and replace with the required code mentioned above. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In your own solution you're already hinting at string replacements, rather than
actual HTML tree insertions. That's because the HTML you're starting from is terrible.

One solution is to add tags to the original tree that was generated by BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

start_str = """<html><body><table class="bt" width="100%"><tr class="heading"><th scope="col">Â </th>
<th class="th-heading" scope="col">B</th>
<th class="tho" scope="col"><b>O</b></th></tr></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html></html>
<th class="thm" scope="col"><b>M</b></th>
<th class="thr" scope="col"><b>R</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>W</b></th>
<th class="thecon" scope="col"><b>E</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>0s</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>F</b></th>
<th class="thw" scope="col"><b>S</b></th>
<th scope="col">Â </th>.............</body></html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(start_str) # remark: this'll split right after the first '</html>'
substr = re.findall('<th class="thm".*', start_str, re.DOTALL)
subsoup = BeautifulSoup(substr[0])
for tag in subsoup.findAll('th'):
    soup.tr.append(tag)
```

While using regular expressions to parse HTML isn't recommended, this is a
borderline case, and it's not even really parsing, merely selecting a substring.
In that sense, it can even be replaced completely with pure python builtins:

```
substr = start_str.split('</html></html>')[1]
```

Another solution is simply to remove those undesired tags, but that will only work if that substring is fixed:

```
to_remove = '</tr></table></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(start_str.split(to_remove)))
```

You could also use the `re` module in this solution, if there is whitespace between those tags for example.